# Flutter - Multiple timers or one timer holds everything

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I'm trying to make a desktop application, I have few functions to call repeatedly at a different times and I have a couple of conditions that I'd like to keep verifying as long as the application is running (such as the connection to a database for example..etc)

```dart
//first approach, having one timer that holds everything
//this is probably a bad example, but you get the idea.

var tick = 0;
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t){
  tick++;
  checkForConnection();
  if(tick == 5){
    doThis();
  }else if(tick == 10){
    dothat();
  }else if(tick == 15){
    ..
  }
  ..
})

//second approach, multiple timers.

Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1) (t) => checkForConnection());
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5) (t) => doThis());
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10) (t) => doThat());
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 15) (t) => ..);
..
```

For the performance, which approach should I go for?

Comment: Well first approach would not do what you want, unless you changed it to use modulus 5 and modulus 10 etc instead of `=`

Comment: Right, but as I mentioned in the comments it's just there to get the idea clear, I haven't yet started working on the actual implementation of that approach.

Comment: Even after fixing the conditions in the first version, the first version is more sensitive to missed `Timer` events.  However, the first version provides a clear guarantee that your code is executed in a specific sequence.